# SDF to URDF conversion

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, sdf, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I am starting from scratch with ROS (just recently installed Jade) and I wanted to ask for some guidance. I have followed all basic ROS tutorials already and my idea was to develop a simulation model with Gazebo that I can control  through ROS nodes. I would afterwards move on to the real robot but only after the simulation model is complete and working properly.

I followed Gazebo's basic tutorials as well (still have some to go through) but the first problem I encountered is my robot has mecanum wheels. I read that the easiest way to go is using the Planar Move Plugin so I looked it up in [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) and apparently I should first develop a URDF file of my robot. I have been going through the tutorials (first had to learn tf) but I am starting to wonder. Do I really need the URDF file? Is there any way to work directly with SDF files both in ROS and gazebo or at least generate the URDF from the SDF I already have?

I would really appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210501/sdf-to-urdf-conversion/) by [maztentropy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22392/maztentropy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a pull request available for a sdf to urdf converter. I downloaded the source and it worked for me, however, if you have any plugins specified in your SDF, i dont think the person who made the pull request got around to converting plugins in SDF to URDF yet, as i had to manually copy the plugins over to the URDF.

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/pull-request/165/urdf-format-support-in-sdf/diff

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rarcturusblack](https://answers.ros.org/users/95043/rarcturusblack/) on 2022-04-19**:
hi!
The bitbucket link doesn't work anymore. Is there a converter? I couldn't find one, I'm using ROS noetic, sdf 1.7 and gazebo 11.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you can't avoid URDF. See this [answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1310/sdf-to-urdf-converter/). Here is a [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) describing how to work with URDF in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

So it's not a full converter per se, but there's a parser plugin [sdformat_urdf](https://github.com/ros/sdformat_urdf) which converts an SDF XML into URDF C++ DOM structures. Though there are some limitations as not all fields are compatible like for example if you have any sensors attached to a joint, it won't be parsed. More details here: https://github.com/ros/sdformat_urdf/tree/ros2/sdformat_urdf